# export c# generic class to excel csv there is 1 column showing data with 1.11254E+17

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I am using a method I found on stackoverflow for exporting from C# a List  to .csv file

I open the file up and my  WavName column shows

```
1.11254E+17
```

SHOULD show

```
"111254006420170506"
```

why is this happening?  do I need to fix in C# or just fix in Excel?

```
public class FinalFile
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string MainId { get; set; }
    public string WavName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    public string folder { get; set; }

}
```

Code I found

```
 WriteCSV(finalFile, @"C:\temp\matchingMainWav.csv");

    public static void WriteCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string path)
    {
        Type itemType = typeof(T);
        var props = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                            .OrderBy(p => p.Name);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.Name)));

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))));
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I must be doing something wrong as when I double click in excel on that value they all seem to be  `111270196720170000`

Comment: Do you need to explicitly tell it it's a BigInt? I've have times where large numbers get converted to scientific and I've had to convert them to BigInt then a string.

Comment: I'm thinking that I must have to change something in my method that I posted,  but I don't see where to change it,  do you?

Comment: If you export it to a txt file is it right? If it is it's probably Excel converting it. PNuts is right - treat it like a text string and put quotes around it.

Comment: Can you open the CSV file in a text editor and see what the number looks like there? My guess is Excel is just displaying it with scientific notation - and also truncating the digits because it only stores a certain number of significant digits.

Comment: You also need to ensure that the value returned from `p.GetValue(item, null)` isn't a string containing `"` or `,`. If it does you need to escape those values out.

Comment: I changed property from string to long and then set to do   `final.WavName = Convert.ToInt64(wav.ParsedName);`    but I still end up in Excel with `111254006420170000`

Comment: @Enigmativity   --  Oh, if I open in notepad++ I do see the correct value `111254006420170506`  etc..    So the whole point was that thousands of records need to be imported into sql server...  I typically do web development  but I didn't want to obviously create a website or even insert from c# into sql server 1 record at a time in a loop  ( yes I know there are bulk copy stuff)    so I was just exporting only to end up manually importing into sql server ...

Comment: So hopefully skipping excel and selecting a csv for data import should just end up putting it into the current column ( I need to create a new database table for this and determine which datatypes to use )

Comment: The issue has to do with excel defaults cells to general formatting.  General formatting will reformat data.  Setting columns in excel to correct formatting before importing will prevent this from happening or putting data in double quotes will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "=/"" at the start of your data and "/"" at the end of your data.

**like:"=/""+phonenum+"/""**